# How do I make a background image scroll and not be tiled on the page?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image for my website, and when I sourced the image in Html it tiles across the page and stops in the same place. How can I resize the image to fill the window and scroll down the page so that the text and stuff just appears to be travelling up the page?
 I've used the code in your answer and the image shows and isnt tiled but it repeats down the page instead of scrolling down?

```
<body background="D:\Documents and Settings\HOME\Desktop\Nathan Taylor\Mancuerda\Web Page\Background copy.jpg" background style="fixed">
<style type="text/css">
html{
    background-image: url(D:\Documents and Settings\HOME\Desktop\Nathan Taylor\Mancuerda\Web Page\Background copy.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

There's the script I'm using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Updated** with jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q5WKg/1/

To stop the background from repeating you want to do in your CSS:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

To have the background always fill use the css3 property:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Because its not been widely implemented you will probably need to use vendor prefixes:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

In addition to your comments - in full it would look something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html
{
    background-image: url('path/to/imagefile.jpg'); 
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

}
</style>
```

If your background image was on the html element.

***Update 2**

I would correct your code above, move your style declaration in to the head of the document (although where you put it will work fine in most browsers) and remove any info regarding the background image from the body tag.

Also the url you are providing is an absolute path to the file on your computer - you need to be using relative paths really, and not paths that are dependant on your computers file structure, I'm assuming that the HTML document is in the same folder as "Background copy.jpg".  Therefore your code should read as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
html{
    background: url('Background copy.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
CONTENT
</body>
</html>
```

In addition to the updates to your code, I would change the name of any images you use to all be lowercase and to contain no spaces in their filenames - this will save you a lot of headache further down the line...

If you want to better understand how HTML/CSS works, and how to structure them properly I would read up at w3cschools, they have the option to "try it yourself" on a lot of pages which means you can see how the code should be structured and test out different things with CSS & HTML.

w3schools css tutorials - http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp

Comment: Thanks so would it be:
<script type="text/css">
{ 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;}
</script>
is that right?

Comment: Hi @NathanTaylor, I've update the answer :) you say you have a background image - how are you setting this background image? With CSS?  I'm assuming it is set with CSS on the `body` element

Comment: im not to sure its a very basic html code im new to coding so im just playing about with it the code is something like <image source= Filepath/image.jpg> then ive got <div settings I don't have access to my code as im at work this is a personal project

Comment: Ah ok, well I've updated the above to include `background-image`, you should update this to reference your background image, and remove other occurrences, you shouldn't really be setting a background image using `<img src="*" />` .... :)

Comment: ive tried this with my code and it doesnt seem to work the picture doesnt show any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some example code?  Just make sure the url to the background image is correct and you should be able to see it fine, try adding `width:100%; height:100%;` if they don't work please supply some example code :)

Comment: There are a couple of tweaks to the code too you should follow ;)

Comment: It keeps saying my code is incorrect even though its the one you gave me and it works in notepad when i try to show it as code it says it is not valid code :@

Comment: Its hard to guess what is going on does the jsFiddle work for you?  If it does then you just need to copy that... can you provide some sample code? Can you upload your code online somewhere like jsfiddle or  http://pastebin.com/ ?

Comment: ive added the script now i was having difficulty pasting it into the question

Answer (score 3):

Probably this:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/your_file.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

For IE - IE9+ only, other browsers - should work.

Much more info here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

P.S. You *might* also be interested in parallax.

Answer (score 1):

Set a few options for your background-image:

```
html,body{

    background-image: url('your/image/path');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; // this fills up the complete page.
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

In this site's version, it works perfectly. here's the code:

```
html { 
background: url("image.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```